# Take an inputted value, multiply by contents of <td> and display result in another <td> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table, each row has a number of td's. One of the td's contains a number input box.

I'm now trying to use jQuery to take the inputted number, multiply it by a number inside another td in the same row and then make the result display in another td (same row) but so far I can't seem to get it working.

Not sure if I'm missing something simple or I'm completely off the mark

Here is my HTML

```
<table class="my-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Header 1</td>
            <td>Header 2</td>
            <td>Header 3</td>
            <td>Header 4</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-row-num="1">
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td><span class="numerator">10</span> / 1</td>
        <td><form><input type="number"></form></td>
        <td class="rowtotal">£0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr data-row-num="1">
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td><span class="numerator">10</span> / 1</td>
        <td><form><input type="number"></form></td>
        <td class="rowtotal">£0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr data-row-num="1">
        <td>Item 3</td>
        <td><span class="numerator">10</span> / 1</td>
        <td><form><input type="number"></form></td>
        <td class="rowtotal">£0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is my jQuery so far

```
//Finds inputted text in table and binds to function calculateSum?
$(function () {
    var tbl = $('.my-table');
    tbl.find('input[type=number]').bind("keyup", function () {
    calculateSum();
    });
});

//Finds numerator and multiplies by input, outputs result?
function calculateSum() {
    var tbl = $('.my-table');
    tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
        var numeratorValue = $(this).find('.numerator');
        var numerator = numeratorValue.html;
        $(this).find('input[type=number]').each(function () {
            var result = $(this).val * numerator;
            $('.rowtotal').html('£' + result);
        });
    });
}
```

Any help most appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/mu4m4ghv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `input` event instead of `keyup`, this will work any kind of change of value. Take parent `tr` and then find `.numerator` text in it. After that multiply the `input` value with `.numerator` text and set it to `.rowtotal`.

```
$('input[type=number]').on("input", function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var num = this.value;
    var numerator = tr.find('.numerator').text();
    tr.find('.rowtotal').text('£' + num * numerator);
});
```

**Full Code**

```js
$('input[type=number]').on("input", function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var num = this.value;
    var numerator = tr.find('.numerator').text();
    tr.find('.rowtotal').text('£' + num * numerator);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="my-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Header 1</td>
            <td>Header 2</td>
            <td>Header 3</td>
            <td>Header 4</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-row-num="1">
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td><span class="numerator">10</span> / 1</td>
            <td><form><input type="number"></form></td>
            <td class="rowtotal">£0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr data-row-num="1">
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td><span class="numerator">10</span> / 1</td>
            <td><form><input type="number"></form></td>
            <td class="rowtotal">£0</td>
        </tr>

        <tr data-row-num="1">
            <td>Item 3</td>
            <td><span class="numerator">10</span> / 1</td>
            <td><form><input type="number"></form></td>
            <td class="rowtotal">£0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving off `()` when you are calling jQuery methods ... like `val` should be `val()` and `html` should be `html()`

Also these values will be strings